# How to fix `Unable to cast Controller as Controller Type error` - ApiController issues

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, ninject, .net-core-2.2

I am creating a .net core angular website and running into issues with the ApiController's where the ApiController (ordered alphabetically asc) will run but all others will fail with a 500 error claiming the below:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'AbcController' to type 'AccController'.

lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
```

Creating .net core 2.2 website using angular and ninject (the main parts relevant). I have set it up the same as an existing project where the ApiControllers work, but am getting 500 errors. I have tried changing between the following:

- Setting both as Controller
- Setting both as ControllerBase
- Creating a BaseController that both extend where BaseController is Controller
- Creating a BaseController that both extend where BaseController is ControllerBase
- Added/Removed tags for ApiController in Controllers
- Added/Removed tags for Route in Controllers
- Added/Removed manual setting of MVC pathing
- Reordered app.### configure options such as UseStaticFiles() and UseMvc()

~Controller 1~

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AbcController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Get")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return this.Ok("ABC hello world");
        }
    }
```

~Controller 2~

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Get")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return this.Ok("ACC hello world");
        }
    }
```

Startup Configure Method

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        Kernel = RegisterApplicationComponents(app, loggerFactory);

        app.Use(async (context, next) => { await next.Invoke(); });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseHttpMiddleware();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

Current result, to trying to call `api/Abc/Get` is valid response, 200 result.
Current result, to trying to call `api/Acc/Get` is 500, with full error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'AbcController' to type 'AccController'.
```

Comment: I have no problems running it if I remove the `RegisterApplicationComponents` and `app.UseHttpMiddleware. Are these custom methods you've written? Can you add them to your question, along with `ConfigureServices`?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2309376/simply-ged prompted me to check through the 2 extra methods, and have regone through some of the older code. Looks like ninject was causing issues. It was only mapping some of the controllers, as stated above. I have since removed ninject, moving to purely using

```
    services.AddSingleton<ITestService, TestService>();
```

which has since resolved that issue.